# Understanding this jQuery code with function assignment and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load some JavaScript files via a custom loader. Previously I was using `document.write()` to write all of my files out, but I want to make use of jQuery. I'm definitely no expert in jQuery, only using some of the more basic features and functionality, so I took to the web. Well, i found the following piece of code, which DOES work, but I'm having a little trouble understanding it. Here is the code:

```
(function() {
    // Poll for jQuery to come into existence
    var checkReady = function(callback) {
        if (window.jQuery) {
            callback(jQuery);
        }
        else {
            window.setTimeout(function() { checkReady(callback); }, 100);
        }
    };

    // Start polling...
    checkReady(function($) {
        // Use $ here...
    });
})();
```

I understand the fact that the code is checking to see if jQuery is available, and if not, it will keep checking every second. I also understand the fact that if it is available, the code under the "Polling" will execute. What I'm not understanding, and what I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around, is the whole `callback` parameter and the `checkReady` variable.
`checkReady` is both a variable as well as a function? If it's a variable which is a function in the top section, how can it have a different function associated with it in the code in the lower section? Also, what is the callback parameter actually doing?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/, http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/. To give a start: Functions are values, just like any other data type, such as strings or numbers, and therefore can also be passed around like any other value. `callback` is a function which is called bu `checkReady`.

Comment: *"checkReady is both a variable as well as a function?"* Yes. JavaScript functions are objects. They can be passed around just like any other data. The `callback` parameter is the developer's code that is invoked when `jQuery` is finally found.

Comment: ...here's a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2kT8/) showing a function passed to another function.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, functions are *first-class*, meaning that they can be assigned to variables, passed as arguments and treated as you would any other variable, like a `5` or `"foo"`.

What you're seeing here `var checkReady = function(callback) { ... }` is the function being assigned to the variable `checkReady`.

What you're seeing here `checkReady(function($) { ... });` is checkReady being *called* with the *[anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)* `function($) { ... }` as its argument. Inside the function `checkReady` this is referred to with the `callback` parameter. An anonymous function just means you have a literal function there without a name, just like having a string literal `"foo"` you can call `alert("foo");` without naming it `var str="foo"; alert(str);` You can do the same thing with functions. They can be named or put inline as literal things without names.

What you're seeing here `window.setTimeout(function() { checkReady(callback); }, 100);` is `window.setTimeout` being called with an anonymous function `function() { ... }`, set to be executed in 100 milliseconds. In 100 milliseconds, it executes the function, which contains a recursive call back to `checkReady` with the same `callback` argument it got in the first place.

So what is `callback` doing? It's intended to contain everything you want to do after you're sure JQuery is loaded. Basically it's the substance of your program. *You're passing your whole program around like it's any other variable*, to another function that checks things every so often and calls it when it's ready. This is the beauty of [first-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this pretty picture will help

```
 +-----------                      +------------+
 |          |                      |            |
 |       ...v.................     V            |
 |  +- - checkReady = function(callback) - -+   |
 |  :                              |        :   |
 |  :   callback() <-execute this--+        :   |
 |  :                anon func              :   |
 |  :                                       :   |
 |  +- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+   |
 |  :                                       :   |
 |  :                  +----------------------->+
 |  :                  |                    :   |
 |  :                  ^                    :   |
 +<---- checkReady(callback);               :   |
 |  :   call itself, sending the same       :   |
 |  :   anonymous callback function         :   |
 |  :                                       :   |
 |  +- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -+   |
 |                                              |
 +-calls+                                       |
        |                                       |
        ^                                       |
    checkReady(function($) {                    |
        // this anon func goes here  >----------+
    });
```

Comment: This helps a lot....I think. So the bottom checkReady is calling the top checkReady, and passing in the anonymous function contained in  the bottom checkReady as a parameter to the top checkReady. If jQuery is available, the anonymous function from the bottom is executed, otherwise checkReady calls itself again, passing in the anonymous function from the bottom checkReady as a parameter again. Did I follow that right?

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
var name = function (params...) { ... statements ... };
```

creates an unnamed (anonymous) function and puts the reference to it into the "name" variable. It is important that this code does not create "name" function. "name" only stores reference to the function. This reference can be copied to another variable and then the function can be called via this another variable as follows:

```
var newName = name;
newName(); // invokes the function
```

I think that you may find this interesting if you want to read more about the JavaScript functions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions